# Images are not displayed in the output file

Tags: graphics

Hi could someone please advise on why it is that my images do not render in the tex file which I am compiling using Winedt10. I have saved the images in the folder as the tex file and all the names are consistent. Please see the following code:

```
\title{Testing images } 

\author{
        John Doe\\            
}

\date{\today}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This is a document to test the inclusion of images in tex document on winedt.

\includegraphics{figure1.png}

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{simple}

\end{document}
```

The process stalls and gives the following error:

```
"l.18 \includegraphics{figure1.png}

? 

Process has been terminated ..."
```

Thanks for any assistance.

The log file reads as:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6350 64-bit) (preloaded format=latex 2017.8.29)  29 AUG 2017 16:01
entering extended mode
**./image.tex
(image.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2016/11/05 v2.16a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks14
\ex@=\dimen103
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count87
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 213.
\uproot@=\count88
\leftroot@=\count89
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 375.
\classnum@=\count90
\DOTSCASE@=\count91
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 596.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 712.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 713.
\macc@depth=\count92
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count93
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count94
\dspbrk@lvl=\count95
\tag@help=\toks15
\row@=\count96
\column@=\count97
\maxfields@=\count98
\andhelp@=\toks16
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks17
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks18
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2817.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks19
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2017/04/14 v1.1b Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 99.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\dvips.def"
File: dvips.def 2016/07/10 v3.1a Driver-dependent file (DPC,SPQR)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen112
\Gin@req@width=\dimen113
) (image.aux)
\openout1 = `image.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 12.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 13.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd"
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 13.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd"
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
) (image.bbl

LaTeX Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 3.

) [1

] (image.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1442 strings out of 493324
 16574 string characters out of 3139092
 69826 words of memory out of 3000000
 5006 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 7442 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,6n,26p,223b,199s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on image.dvi (1 page, 660 bytes).
```

Comment: Why do you  write `\title`, `\author`, `\date` *before* `\documentclass`?

Comment: @Bernard This does not cause any problems rendering the document.

Comment: Where is your graphic file?

Comment: @Bernard It is in the same folder on my desktop as my tex file.

Comment: Well, I have no problem with your code, so there must be something else.

Comment: Can you show the complete `.log` file instead of the small extract?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I added it now, let me know if I should delete it again, it looks quite chaotic.

Comment: @Bernard The \includegraphics part is displayed as underlined for some reason. Is this an indication of something?

Comment: One thing I note is that you're generating a DVI file, i.e. you're using `latex` to make the output. I don't think PNG images can be used with DVI output, what if you use `pdflatex` to generate a PDF directly?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are right thanks a lot. It is rendering something now using PDFlatex, a bit skew but it is showing now.